# "HDD Status" in ipmitool sensor output

Tags: linux, ipmi, supermicro, ipmitool

I have a Supermicro "SuperServer 1028U-TR4+" box (motherboard: X10DRU-i+).

I use command

```
ipmitool -H <ipmi_ip> -U <ipmi_user> -P <ipmi_password> sensor
```

and get this output:

```
...
Chassis Intru | 0x0 | discrete | 0x0000| na | na | na | na | na | na
PS1 Status | 0x1 | discrete | 0x0100| na | na | na | na | na | na
PS2 Status | 0x1 | discrete | 0x0100| na | na | na | na | na | na
AOC_SAS Temp | 63.000 | degrees C | ok | -11.000 | -8.000 | -5.000 | 100.000 | 105.000 | 110.000
HDD Temp | 34.000 | degrees C | ok | -11.000 | -8.000 | -5.000 | 95.000 | 100.000 | 105.000
HDD Status | 0x1 | discrete | 0x0100| na | na | na | na | na | na
```

What does "HDD Status" mean? I can not find documentation on it.

**UPD:**

```
ipmitool -H <ipmi_ip> -U <ipmi_user> -P <ipmi_password> sdr elist 
CPU1 Temp        | 01h | ok  |  3.1 | 41 degrees C
CPU2 Temp        | 02h | ok  |  3.2 | 40 degrees C
PCH Temp         | 0Ah | ok  |  7.1 | 39 degrees C
System Temp      | 0Bh | ok  |  7.2 | 22 degrees C
Peripheral Temp  | 0Ch | ok  |  7.3 | 35 degrees C
MB_10G Temp1     | 6Ah | ns  | 11.1 | No Reading
MB_10G Temp2     | 6Bh | ns  | 11.2 | No Reading
Vcpu1VRM Temp    | 10h | ok  |  3.3 | 30 degrees C
Vcpu2VRM Temp    | 11h | ok  |  3.4 | 32 degrees C
VmemABVRM Temp   | 12h | ok  | 32.49 | 30 degrees C
VmemCDVRM Temp   | 13h | ok  | 32.50 | 28 degrees C
VmemEFVRM Temp   | 14h | ok  | 32.51 | 26 degrees C
VmemGHVRM Temp   | 15h | ok  | 32.52 | 34 degrees C
P1-DIMMA1 Temp   | B0h | ok  | 32.1 | 27 degrees C
P1-DIMMA2 Temp   | B1h | ns  | 32.2 | No Reading
P1-DIMMA3 Temp   | B2h | ns  | 32.3 | No Reading
P1-DIMMB1 Temp   | B4h | ok  | 32.4 | 25 degrees C
P1-DIMMB2 Temp   | B5h | ns  | 32.5 | No Reading
P1-DIMMB3 Temp   | B6h | ns  | 32.6 | No Reading
P1-DIMMC1 Temp   | B8h | ok  | 32.8 | 27 degrees C
P1-DIMMC2 Temp   | B9h | ns  | 32.9 | No Reading
P1-DIMMC3 Temp   | BAh | ns  | 32.10 | No Reading
P1-DIMMD1 Temp   | BCh | ok  | 32.12 | 25 degrees C
P1-DIMMD2 Temp   | BDh | ns  | 32.13 | No Reading
P1-DIMMD3 Temp   | BEh | ns  | 32.14 | No Reading
P2-DIMME1 Temp   | D0h | ok  | 32.16 | 23 degrees C
P2-DIMME2 Temp   | D1h | ns  | 32.17 | No Reading
P2-DIMME3 Temp   | D2h | ns  | 32.18 | No Reading
P2-DIMMF1 Temp   | D4h | ok  | 32.20 | 24 degrees C
P2-DIMMF2 Temp   | D5h | ns  | 32.21 | No Reading
P2-DIMMF3 Temp   | D6h | ns  | 32.22 | No Reading
P2-DIMMG1 Temp   | D8h | ok  | 32.24 | 23 degrees C
P2-DIMMG2 Temp   | D9h | ns  | 32.25 | No Reading
P2-DIMMG3 Temp   | DAh | ns  | 32.26 | No Reading
P2-DIMMH1 Temp   | DCh | ok  | 32.28 | 24 degrees C
P2-DIMMH2 Temp   | DDh | ns  | 32.29 | No Reading
P2-DIMMH3 Temp   | DEh | ns  | 32.30 | No Reading
FAN1             | 41h | ns  | 29.1 | No Reading
FAN2             | 42h | ok  | 29.2 | 3200 RPM
FAN3             | 43h | ok  | 29.3 | 3400 RPM
FAN4             | 44h | ok  | 29.4 | 3800 RPM
FAN5             | 45h | ok  | 29.5 | 3900 RPM
FAN6             | 46h | ok  | 29.6 | 3400 RPM
FAN7             | 47h | ok  | 29.7 | 3500 RPM
FAN8             | 48h | ns  | 29.8 | No Reading
FAN9             | 49h | ns  | 29.9 | No Reading
12V              | 30h | ok  |  7.17 | 12 Volts
5VCC             | 31h | ok  |  7.18 | 5 Volts
3.3VCC           | 32h | ok  |  7.19 | 3.30 Volts
VBAT             | 33h | ok  |  7.20 | 3.24 Volts
Vcpu1            | 34h | ok  |  3.5 | 1.81 Volts
Vcpu2            | 36h | ok  |  3.6 | 1.81 Volts
VDIMMAB          | 35h | ok  | 32.33 | 1.18 Volts
VDIMMCD          | 37h | ok  | 32.34 | 1.17 Volts
VDIMMEF          | 3Ah | ok  | 32.35 | 1.18 Volts
VDIMMGH          | 3Bh | ok  | 32.36 | 1.18 Volts
5VSB             | 38h | ok  |  7.21 | 4.97 Volts
3.3VSB           | 39h | ok  |  7.22 | 3.38 Volts
1.5V PCH         | 3Ch | ok  |  7.23 | 1.50 Volts
1.2V BMC         | 3Dh | ok  |  7.24 | 1.20 Volts
1.05V PCH        | 3Eh | ok  |  7.25 | 1.04 Volts
Chassis Intru    | AAh | ok  | 23.1 | 
PS1 Status       | C4h | ok  | 10.1 | Presence detected
PS2 Status       | C5h | ok  | 10.2 | Presence detected
AOC_SAS Temp     | 0Fh | ok  |  1.4 | 56 degrees C
HDD Temp         | 50h | ok  |  1.4 | 33 degrees C
HDD Status       | 54h | ok  |  4.1 | Drive Present
```

Also, i see the short switching of this sensor to 0
periodically. I want know what this means.

Comment: As you can see from this output (at the very end): `HDD Status       | 54h | ok  |  4.1 | Drive Present` `HDD Status` means if the drive is present and in your case its OK.

Comment: @bangal OK, what means HDD Status is 0x0? HDD not present? Which one? All?

Comment: First, pls, post the output again.

Comment: @bangal I add output `sdr elist` to question.

Comment: you may like to also run: `ipmitool -H <ipmi_ip> -U <ipmi_user> -P <ipmi_password> sdr get "HDD Status"` for more detailed info.

Comment: @bangal Not work for me. `$ ipmitool ...cuted... sdr get "HDD Status"
Unable to find sensor id 'HDD Status'`

Comment: Then try with: `ipmitool -H <ipmi_ip> -U <ipmi_user> -P <ipmi_password> sensor get "HDD Status"`

Comment: @bangal Don't work too: `Sensor data record "HDD Status" not found!`

Comment: I guess the sensor name is not correct. Anyway, you can try running `ipmitool ... sdr -v` for detailed info, and find out the correct name. I have added a link in my answer. Check it and take your time to try those commands and see. You will find more useful info I'm sure. The additionl question you have asked, is not clear to me and there is nothing more to add from my side. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contact to Supermicro, they offered upgrading to the [latest](http://supermicro.com/support/bios/firmware0.aspx) IPMI firmware (v 03.26). Blinking of this sensor is bug, fixed in this firmware version.

Answer (score 7):

`ipmitool` might use `sensor number` and `sensor name` for command output. You can use the following command to print the command output in a more friendly format:

```
ipmitool -H <ipmi_ip> -U <ipmi_user> -P <ipmi_password> sdr elist
```

This will output all sensor names in your server mapped to the corresponding sensor numbers.

As can be seen from the output you posted, **HDD status** checks if drive/s is/are present and if the status is ok:

> HDD Status | 54h | ok | 4.1 | Drive Present

In the output: the *sensor name* is in the first column and the corresponding *sensor number* is in the second column.

For a very detailed info, you can try running:

```
ipmitool -H <ipmi_ip> -U <ipmi_user> -P <ipmi_password> sdr -v
```

---

Here is a link to some very useful `ipmitool` commands:

https://www.thomas-krenn.com/de/wiki/Ipmitool_zur_Sensorabfrage_von_Servern_nutzen

Although the page is in german, but commands and explanations are in english, so it should not be too difficult to *read* it I hope ;)

---

For official references and documentaion:

[Intelligent Platform Management Interface Specification v2.0 rev. 1.1](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/servers/ipmi/ipmi-second-gen-interface-spec-v2-rev1-1.html)

[IPMI Technical Resources](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/servers/ipmi/ipmi-technical-resources.html)